# Remove duct tape adhesive residue from fabric

Tags: adhesives, restoration

I have an article of clothing that had duct tape on it at one point, but after pulling off the duct tape residue remains.

I've debated buying Goo Gone but I am worried about discoloration. 
The fabric is all black, no patterns.

What would be the best way to remove the duct tape adhesive residue, without affecting coloration? Has anyone used Goo Gone before? Are there alternative methods that can be used?

**EDIT:** I've confirmed with the company that manufactured the clothing that it is 94% Polyester and 6% Spandex

Comment: What kind of fabric is this?

Comment: I believe it is some kind of fleece but I would have to check the tag. I will post back later when I can get my hands on it again.

Comment: Did you check the fiber content yet?  It would be great to let the people who tried to help you know.

Comment: Hey all, sorry for the delay, when I checked the tag it was completely worn out so I had to email the company I bought it from and they *just* gave me a reply. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Goo Gone and similar products work quite well on hard surfaces for removing adhesive residue. You will find that the recommendations for such products also include testing on a hidden portion or similar piece.

It's likely that Goo Gone will work and you may be able to soak the fabric in the liquid to allow better penetration. Once soaked for a while, a detergent wash is likely to be needed to remove the oiliness of GG.

Alternatives to GG include WD-40, with the same oiliness factor, as well as baby oil, mineral oil and peanut butter.

Work the selected substance in the fabric frequently to ensure good distribution.

A quick search using "goo gone fabrics" shows that many posts have been made to indicate the product works on clothing.

Of all the above, I think peanut butter involves the most effort and perhaps the lowest risk of discoloration, but I've never used peanut butter!

Answer (score 2):

There are three key variables to consider with this problem:  fiber content, fabric construction, and dyeing method.

The **fleece fabric construction** is sort of a worst case because there is so much surface area for the adhesive to stick to that you won't be able to freeze the fabric and try to scrape it off - which is a good technique for getting sticky stuff like gum or adhesive off of flat fabrics.

If the **fiber content** is polyester, you probably can safely use a goo-be-gone product because it's most likely that the fiber was solution dyed, which means the dye is actually part of the fiber, not an add-on. (Dye is added to the solution before being extruded into a fiber shape.)

Even though goo-be-gone should be OK to use on polyester fleece, it's safest to apply a little with a Q-tip somewhere that doesn't show, like the inside of the side seam.

If the fleece is a **natural fiber** like cotton, you definitely need to do a test first because the dye will likely be less stable.

Textile dyeing can be conducted at the fiber, yarn, fabric or garment stages.  The earlier in the process the dyeing occurs, i.e at the fiber or yarn stage, the more stable and durable.  However, fiber and yarn dying are typically more expensive processes than fabric or garment dyeing so it's done less often.

Possible complication:  Sometimes black fabrics of any fiber content have been overdyed - the fabric or garment may have been dyed a fashion color that didn't sell well, and then dyed black.

There is much about end-use textiles that is invisible to the human eye and to the average consumer.  Without knowing fiber content and how the item was processed and dyed, there is always a risk when experimenting with chemicals on textiles.

Always test on a place that won't be seen, or take the item to a reputable dry-cleaner.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Eucalyptus Oil. Apply with an old tooth brush, scrub gently until the residue starts to loosen, clean the brush with a paper towel and reapply oil until residue is gone. Wash as normal :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use vinegar mixed with water or small amount of nail varnish remover (acetone).  By using it gently and using less nail varnish remover nothing will happen to your fabric colour.

Comment: I don't think you can ever promise that "nothing will happen to your fabric" when you are using (even dilute) chemicals on textiles.  Any time you apply vinegar (weak Acetic Acid) or Acetone to colored fabrics, it's best to test on a hidden area that will not be seen.